# Why is there a border around my image?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why there is a white border around the top image.

**this is the CSS**

```
font {
font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.intro{
background:url(../images/2167265210_bf48820f23_o.jpg);
background-position: center;
height: 600px;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 100;
}
.intro h1{
font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:100;
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

**this is the HTML**

```
<div class="intro">
<h1>blabla</h1>
<a href="mailto:dingen@dingen.nl" class="button">Neem contact op</a>
</div>
```

I hope anyone can help me!

Comment: A screenshot showing the border you're talking about and the picture itself would help.

Comment: Why are you using `-o-background-size: cover;`?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot or the image or a jsfiddle with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE puts borders around images, as other browsers don't. That's some weird bug, but here's how to fix it:

```
.intro{
 background:url(../images/2167265210_bf48820f23_o.jpg);
 background-position: center;
 height: 600px;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 100;

 border:0px;
 outline:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possibilties, but without a screenshot or a working fiddle i cant see the excact problem.

1. A white border in the image itself
2. A white border created by the browser around the image
3. The default browser margin
4. Maybe the margin from the h1

**Solution for 1:** Edit the image.

**Solution for 2,3,4:** 
Use `border:none;` for the image, or `margin:0` for the `body` and `<h1>` like here.

```
img { border:none; }                     /* Border around the image */
html, body {margin:0; padding:0;}        /* Default margin from browsers */
h1 {margin:0; padding:0;}                /* Default margin/padding from the h1 */
```

But without a printscreen or a Jsfiddle, i dont see the excact problem.

Comment: That might fix it but the picture itself could also have whitespace in it :)

Comment: True, thats why we need some more than just the code, for example te image itself.